# Linq group by but return all properties

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list with objects that looks something like this.

```
  public class Resource
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PersonFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PersonLastName { get; set; }


    public string VisitName { get; set; }


    public VisitPlan[] Visits { get; set; }

}

public class VisitPlan
{
    public DateTime StartAfter { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartBefore { get; set; }
    public Competence[] Skills { get; set; }
}


public class Competence {

    public Guid Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

Currently the list contains several items with the same ClientSSN, FirstName and LastName.

I would like to group them to so that it looks more like this and does not have duplicate client information.

```
public class Client {

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public Visit[] Visits { get; set; }
}


public class Visit {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartBefore { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartAfter { get; set; }


}
```

I did a simple group by that grouped by SSN and visits but then I am only able to access the SSN and the visits.

```
                var results = from v in visits
                          group v.Visits by v.PersonId into g
                          select new { 
                              PersonID = g.Key, 
                              Visits = g.ToList(),

                          };
```

Another possibility is maybe to use a temporary list, but I cant get the logic right in my head.

Comment: If you provide your classes you should provide code that compiles, otherwise we can't test it directly. _"I did a simple group by that grouped by SSN and visits"_ Where is that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from r in Resources
group r by new { 
   r.PersonId, 
   r.PersonFirstName,
   r.PersonLastName
} into g
select new Client {
    ClientId = g.Key.PersonId,
    FirstName = g.Key.PersonFirstName,
    LastName = g.Key.PersonLastName,
    Visits = g.SelectMany(r => r.Visits).ToArray()
}
```

NOTE: thus you have two `Visit` classes with exactly same name, I ended with selecting all visits from group instead of creating some other `Visit` instances with `Name` property.

UPDATE: if your first visit class named `VisitPlan` then complete query looks like:

```
from r in Resources
group r by new { 
   r.PersonId, 
   r.PersonFirstName,
   r.PersonLastName
} into g
select new Client {
    ClientId = g.Key.PersonId,
    FirstName = g.Key.PersonFirstName,
    LastName = g.Key.PersonLastName,
    Visits = g.SelectMany(r => 
                 r.Visits.Select(v => new Visit {
                     Name = r.VisitName,
                     StartBefore = v.StartBefore,
                     StartAfter = v.StartAfter
                 })).ToArray();

}
```

Comment: Actually it was my bad, the first Visit name was wrong, it is VisitPlan. Updated the code.

Comment: @isshin OK, updated code - simply create your `Visit` instances

Comment: Thanks seems like exactly what I needed! I have added a list of contacts per client. How would I change the linq to reflect that? I tried doing the same thing you did with visits. The only problem is that contact-personnel will occationally be null.

Comment: @isshin changing your question after it was answered is not very good way to do. You usually should accept answer and ask new question after previous one was answered. I'll give you a hint on what you need, but I'll rollback your edits. Getting contacts: `Contacts = g.SelectMany(r => r.Visits.SelectMany(v => v.Contacts)).ToArray()`

Comment: Sorry, marked your answer as solution. Getting the contact that way does not work though, since contacts are on the Client and not the visit

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I tried out. The only problem now is that they contain duplicate values. Any way to sort them out?

Comment: @isshin simplest way will be selecting distinct anonymous type `Contacts = g.SelectMany(r => r.Contacts).Select(cp => new { cp.PersonnelID, cp.Name }).Distinct().Select(x => new Contact { PersonnelID = x.PersonnelID, Name = x.Name }).ToArray()`